# How to not propagate environmental variables to command of a child process?

Tags: c, environment-variables, fork

I am trying to understand the specifications of a C coding project using fork() and execv().

Essentially, I am told I need to either propagate or not propagate the environment variables of the shell to the command I am executing in a child process depending on a binary value.

Though, regardless, I am supposed to pass in any additional environmental variables I am provided to the command I am executing in the child.

This whole idea is new information to me, so I am just trying to understand what exactly this means.

To my understanding, when a child is created using fork(), the environmental variables of the parent process are passed on to the child, and then any additional environmental variable changes can be made as an argument of the execve() function when it is run within the child.

But if this is the case, then the environmental variables are always propagated from the parent/shell anyway right? So what is the difference and how would I not propagate those variables?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't tag `bash` unless you're actually asking *about bash*.

Answer (score 1):

You're still in control after the `fork()` and before the `execv()`.

You can make changes to your child's environment that you don't want to make to your parent -- including calls to `unsetenv()` -- in that process.

Alternately, you can construct a new environment entirely and pass it in the `envp` argument to `execve()`.

Comment: The complication with `unsetenv()` is that you must know which names to unset.  Getting the entire environment means finding `environ` (a variable not declared in any POSIX header) and stepping through it to see what's there.  But using `unsetenv()` while stepping through the list could invalidate your pointer into the list represented by `environ` — you have to worry about whether `environ` now points somewhere else altogether.  Or collect the names in a first pass, and then weed through the collected names before using `unsetenv()` copiously.

Answer (score 0):

If you understood `fork(2)` then you'll know that the parent and the child are exactly the same (except for the value returned by `fork()`), so the environment of the parent process is exactly the same as the environment of the child.  there's no other way to pass environment to a child process... because `execve(2)` **doesn't create a new process**.  You only load the process' virtual space by loading a new program on it.  And this allows you to change the environment, as it happens with the argument list.  Think of `argc` and `argv` as some way of passing **positional parameters** to a program, and the environment as some way to pass **named parameters** to a program.  Both are exactly the same kind of things, but ones are seek by position, while the others are accessed by name.

But no new process is created on `execve(2)` (nor in any of its variants)